# Best & Secure way of storing data in iOS app

Tags: security, ios6, sqlite, in-app-purchase, data-storage

I am developing one iOS app in which user can add overlay images to existing images. Also user can unlock all those overlay images using in app purchase.I am saving those images in application bundle & storing the image name,id,isUnlocked flag etc in SQLite.

Now my question is it the best & secure way to store data like this or do you suggest some better & secure way ? Also I tried iExplorer to see my SQLite file. I can change the isUnlocked state of image but CAN NOT save that SQLite file again in Documents directory. So is my understanding correct ? Basically I don't want user to use overlay images just by changing the isUnlocked flag from SQLite instead of in app purchase.

I want to submit the app to App Store so may be my approach works correctly. But does it work in Jailbroken iOS devices also ?

Kindly let me know your suggestion & feedback. Thanks in advance

Comment: Trying to prevent illegitimate users from hacking your software will be a difficult endeavor which may not be worth your time.  If the user has to be as advanced to modify your sqlite database, this might be a very small percentage of your target audience.